# Problem with Converting my LSTM Multi-class Classification Model to a Binary Classification Model

Tags: classification, python, lstm

I am a PyTorch newbie and trying to learn by following tutorials. I have implemented a model for a multi-class classification task and now I'd like to use this model for a binary classification task. In the current model below, I've been using "CrossEntropyLoss" and "Linear" activation. My goal is to change this to "BCELoss" and "Sigmoid" activation,  however, this causes me a size mismatch error (batch_size = 64, n_hidden=256, Each target element is either 0 or 1 and each input element is a float value):

> Using a target size (torch.Size([64])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64, 256])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.

```
class ModuleLSTM(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, n_features, n_hidden=256, n_layers=3):        
    super().__init__()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM( ...params... )
    self.classifier = nn.Sigmoid()     # This was: self.classifier = nn.Linear(n_hidden, 2)                    
    
  def forward(self, x):
    self.lstm.flatten_parameters()
    _, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(x)
    hidden = torch.squeeze(hidden, 1)
    output = hidden[-1]
    return self.classifier(output)

class Classifier(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self, n_features, n_classes=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.model = ModuleLSTM(n_features)
    self.criterion = nn.BCELoss()     # This was: self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

  def forward(self, x, labels=None):
    output = self.model(x)
    loss = 0
    if labels is not None:    loss = self.criterion(output, labels)
    return loss, output
   
  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):               
    sequences, labels = batch["sequence"], batch["label"]
    loss, outputs = self(sequences, labels)
    predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
    stepAccuracy = accuracy(predictions, labels)
    return {"loss": loss, "accuracy": stepAccuracy}

 # validation_step, test_step
```

If I use "CrossEntropyLoss" and "Linear" activation instead of "BCELoss" and "Sigmoid", systems works without any problem. In order to make it work, do I need to modify the forward method of ModuleLSTM from scratch to return an output of size "torch.Size([64])", or do I need to just reshape the return value of self.model(x) from "torch.Size([64, 256])" to "torch.Size([64])"? I am afraid of information loss if I follow the second case.

Thanks!